# Membership start and expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Im looking to add a DateTime MembershipStart & MembershipExpiry into my AspNetUser database using Migration. Would i be correct in applying

```
public DateTime MembershipStart { get; set; }
public DateTime MembershipExpiry { get; set; }
```

So when the user registers the first property sets to the current date, and the expiry sets itself a year later from the start date. How would the properties look/ be set? is this good practice? or should i set register with a membership type (viewmodel) and add start and expiry through there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you are showing if the DTO (The one extending IdentityUser).

The DTO itself shouldn't contain any business logic so doing something like defaulting the values is a bad idea.

Your registration process should be the place where you are setting those values.

Comment: Its in the ApplicationUser.cs which extends IdentityUser..so dont do this...public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public DateTime MembershipStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime MembershipExpiration { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            MembershipStart = DateTime.Now;
            MembershipExpiration = MembershipStart.AddYears(1);
        }
               
    }

Comment: as from their i would also be applying a CF Migration

Comment: This is a bad idea because you are adding business logic in the DTO

Comment: if i apply in the RegisterViewModel would that be better?